# Exchange 2010 - Configure Client Access server external domain required?

Tags: exchange-2010

Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 setup asks me to:
"Configure Client Access server external domain"

If we don't allow anyone to access corporate mail from outside the corporate LAN then I should leave this blank?

Leaving this blank will only impact external access i.e. access from outside the LAN? It won't impact access via OWA and Outlook on the corporate LAN?

Is it ok to leave this blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me in a lab setup (exchange 2007); I can't think of any reason it would be a problem if you don't need any external access at all.